# What is the most popular IDE/text editor for developing solidity contracts?

Tags: solidity, ide

Just trying to get a feel for which IDE's are most used and why. I have seen and used many of the tools available (Mix, Ether.camp, Visual Studio), but am looking to see input from Dapp developers as to why they chose their IDE.

I've found Mix to be very buggy (haven't used it in a month or so), and Ether.camp was a little tough to get used to. Haven't tried VS myself...

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!